# For loop mismatching data in js async function

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous, async-await

In the async function `buy()` and `sell()` the values of `x`,`x2` and `y`,`y2` change as the for loop iterates . but this gives wrong data as values of next iteration are fed to values of previous iteration eg `x` of next iteration is used to get values of `x2` of previous iteration. Please help.

```
const Binance = require('node-binance-api');

const total_arr = {};
let total = 0;
const data = {"a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3};

const binance =
    new Binance().options({APIKEY : '<key>', APISECRET : '<secret>'});

async function buy() {
  for (const key in data) {
    var x = await binance.futuresMarketBuy('BNBUSDT', data[key]);
    var x2 = await binance.futuresMarketBuy('BTCUSDT', x);
    total_arr["buy" + key] = x + x2;
  }
}

async function sell() {
  for (const key in data) {
    var y = await binance.futuresMarketSell('BNBUSDT', data[key]);
    var y2 = await binance.futuresMarketSell('BTCUSDT', y);
    total_arr["sell" + key] = y;
  }
}

async function main() {
  await Promise.all([ buy(), sell() ]);
  for (const key in data) {
    total = total + data[key];
  }
  console.log(total);
}

main();
```

Comment: "*values of next iteration are fed to values of previous iteration*" - that cannot possibly happen.

Comment: Why mix `const` with `var`?

Comment: @Bergi What could be the other reasons ? I think the values in later iteration are loading first and being fed to total_arr["buy" + key]  from the previous iteration.

Comment: I didn't understand your second comment.

Comment: What exactly makes you think that loading and storing is out of order? What kind of debugging did you do? If you added logging statements, please show us the outputs of the logs that caused the confusion.

Comment: My second comment meant that you should use `const y` (etc) instead of `var y`. While it should not change the behaviour, it will ensure that the variables won't get overwritten and clarify that the problem is elsewhere.